# cannot implicitly convert type void to int in C#

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private string GetShortName(string LongName)
{
    string ShortFileName = new string('\0', 67);
    **int Result = Support.PInvoke.SafeNative.kernel32.GetShortPathName(ref LongName, ref ShortFileName, ((ShortFileName) is null) ? 0 : Convert.ToString(ShortFileName).Length);**
    ShortFileName = StringsHelper.GetFixedLengthString(ShortFileName, 67);
    return ShortFileName.Substring(0, Math.Min(Result, ShortFileName.Length));
}
```

The above line throws a error "cannot implicitly convert type void to int"
`GetShortPathName` comes from Kernel32.dll that is wrapped in a class file as

```
 public static void GetShortPathName(ref string lpszLongPath, ref string lpszShortPath, int cchBuffer);
```

Is there is any alternative to get it in `int` result?

Comment: Change `GetShortPathName` to return `int` instead of `void`.

Comment: no, because the method does not *return anything*

Comment: `void` method *doesn't return* anything; `Support.PInvoke.SafeNative.kernel32.GetShortPathName(ref LongName, ref ShortFileName, ((ShortFileName) is null) ? 0 : Convert.ToString(ShortFileName).Length);`

Comment: @DStanley it comes from a kernal32 dll ,i cant make the changes

Comment: I'm talking about `Support.PInvoke.SafeNative.kernel32.GetShortPathName` (which is not a framework class). If you don't have control of that then you'll need to define a new wrapper function that _does_ return the `uint`.

Answer (score 1):

[`GetShortPathName`](https://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/kernel32.GetShortPathName) should return a `uint`, not be `void`:

```
public static uint GetShortPathName(...)
```

If you don't have control over `Support.PInvoke.SafeNative.kernel32` then you'll need to create a *new* wrapper around the kernel call that *does* return the `uint`.